# Is it ok to drop .all when there is another call on ActiveRecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am adjusting code working over Profile model to add possibility to activate/deactivate Profile. At some places there was code `Profile.all` and with newly introduced it would be `Profile.active.all`. It seems to me it is ok to drop the `.all` now, but I am not sure if `.all` doesn't do some magicallity.

I checked [docs for all](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.11.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-all) and it mentions default scope. Somehow it seems to me AR should always use default scope unless I call [unscoped](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.11.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-unscoped).

It is definitely not at that many places, so I couldn't change it later. I am just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the code right, most of the query methods are actually being delegated to `:all`. You can avoid that `.all` because ActiveRecord is actually adding that for you with most of them.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b1879124a82b34168412ac699cf6f654e005c4d6/activerecord/lib/active_record/querying.rb

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Querying
    delegate :find, :take, :take!, :first, :first!, :last, :last!, :exists?, :any?, :many?, to: :all
    delegate :second, :second!, :third, :third!, :fourth, :fourth!, :fifth, :fifth!, :forty_two, :forty_two!, to: :all
    delegate :first_or_create, :first_or_create!, :first_or_initialize, to: :all
    delegate :find_or_create_by, :find_or_create_by!, :find_or_initialize_by, to: :all
    delegate :find_by, :find_by!, to: :all
    delegate :destroy, :destroy_all, :delete, :delete_all, :update, :update_all, to: :all
    delegate :find_each, :find_in_batches, to: :all
    delegate :select, :group, :order, :except, :reorder, :limit, :offset, :joins,
             :where, :rewhere, :preload, :eager_load, :includes, :from, :lock, :readonly,
             :having, :create_with, :uniq, :distinct, :references, :none, :unscope, to: :all
    delegate :count, :average, :minimum, :maximum, :sum, :calculate, to: :all
    delegate :pluck, :ids, to: :all
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's safe to remove it.

Just to make sure run this two queries in the console:

```rb
Profile.active.all.to_sql
Profile.active.to_sql
```